# Working with GIT, but export master branch to SVN - branch broken

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I'm working with GIT while developing project, but also I need to update SVN repository that was created for this reason with master branch once a week.  So, would like to export GIT master branch to empty SVN repository.

First of all I need to tell GIT about SVN. I do

```
git svn init http://some/remote/svn/project/
```

Ok, I got lines in gitconfig

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
        url =  http://some/remote/svn/project/
        fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn
```

Now I suppose I can use git svn functionality and I do

```
git svn log
```

but got

```
fatal: your current branch appears to be broken
```

What does it means? How to solve this problem? IS my understanding of doing such things correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git svn log` shows the log of the SVN commits that were imported into the current branch. But you didn't do this, so the branch is "broken" as it is not a branch that is connected to SVN.

Comment: So, how to fill SVN content from GIT then?