# Create commit link between GIT and SVN

Tags: git, git-svn

I have projec in GIT, but now I need to make commit to empty SVN repository also.
I did:

```
git clone https://path/to/git/project1
git svn init -T http://path/to/svn/project1
git svn fetch
```

After I did git svn dcommit I got msg:

```
 Unable to determine upstream SVN information from HEAD history.
```

How to fix it? How to create link from GIT to SVN?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Working with GIT, but export master branch to SVN - branch broken](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42156844/working-with-git-but-export-master-branch-to-svn-branch-broken)